# Is there a way to tell if a Windows binary is a PIE

Tags: windows, binary, position-independent-code

There are a ton of scripts/tools our there to tell if an ELF binary is a position independent executable. Does anyone know of an easy way to tell if a Windows binary is?

Comment: I don't think there is a PE flag for it. x86 PIE PE is probably rare.

Comment: I don't think I've seen any windows code that is non-PIE

Comment: if a binary is compiled with /DYNAMICBASE:NO in cl.exe from visual studio, is it then not a PIE?